# Is checking disc necessary while booting Ubuntu from USB?

Tags: 20.04, live-usb

I am booting Ubuntu from USB. Initially it checks disk for about five minutes. Is this step necessary? Is there any problem if press `ctr + C`?

Comment: A lot of people have said that this disc check is really needed, however note that it has not been included in the lates versions of Ubuntu. The obvious conclusion is that it was a bug.

Comment: For me it seems to have been running for an hour now, stuck at 14%...  I'm wondering if I should stop it....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Removing Disk Check From 20.04 Boot

The command line option `fsck.mode=skip` can be used to skip the disk check when booting Ubuntu 20.04.

The line `Checking disks: 0% complete` may still come up but fsck will not be run, nor will boot time be increased.

Add `fsck.mode=skip` to the `linux line` in /boot/grub/grub.cfg just before `quiet splash` for GRUB boot or in /isolinux/txt.cfg for Syslinux boot.

### `toram`

For those people who think a filesystem check every boot is a good idea.

It takes a little longer to boot `toram`, but the file system check takes about three seconds rather than three minutes, (about sixty times as fast), and the system should run faster once booted.

Add the command `toram` to /boot/grub/grub.cfg or /isolinux/txt.cfg similar to above, or to syslinux.cfg for UNetbootin.

Comment: Can this file be edited during boot?

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi It can be edited during boot, but it is just temporary, Press `Shift` at the start of boot. if Syslinux boot, press `Esc` at language screen, press `F6`, `Esc` and type a space and `fsck.mode=skip`. If GRUB boot press `e` at the menu, then type a space and `fsck.mode=skip` at the end of the entry that starts with "linux". If you Boot `toram` the file check completes in three seconds, not three minutes.

Answer (score 3):

It was introduced because there were many issues reported in the past which turned out to be caused by a corrupted iso. This is to prevent such issues.

Answer (score 3):

Best practice is to let the self-check run the first time.

For subsequent boots, it's safe to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to skip the self-check.

- Cancelling the check after you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> takes a moment - be patient.

Comment: The file filesystem.squashfs is over 2GB and takes most of the time to check. If you can't `Ctrl c` before the check gets to filesystem.squashfs, cancelling is not much use.