# How to install Ubuntu from ISO file?

Tags: boot, grub2, iso

I located iso file on (hd0,gpt7)/iso/ubuntu-20.10-desktop-amd64.iso

On GRUB commandline, I typed like below.

```
set root=(hd0,gpt7)
set iso=/iso/ubuntu-20.10-desktop-amd64.iso
loopback l $iso
linux (l)/casper/vmlinuz root=casper iso-scan/filename=$iso
initrd (l)/casper/initrd
boot
```

Ubuntu booted. But could not installed Ubuntu with error. It took so many hours checking system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is checking disc necessary while booting Ubuntu from USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299014/is-checking-disc-necessary-while-booting-ubuntu-from-usb)

Comment: If it took that long to check the system, you would do well to verify the .iso.

Comment: You need to add the parameter `toram` at the end of the linux line if you want to install Ubuntu to a running system  Then you will need to unmount isodevice before installing. `sudo umount -lrf /isodevice`. I will write out a proper answer for you. The procedure is similar to the instructions on this page: https://askubuntu.com/questions/855039/can-ubuntu-be-installed-to-the-pendrive-it-was-booted-from

Answer (score 4):

### Installing Ubuntu to Internal HDD from ISO booted on the HDD

Your /boot/grub/grub.cfg file should have a menuentry similar to:

```
menuentry "isoname ISO" {
    set root=(hdX,Y)
    set isofile="/[path]/[name].iso"
        loopback loop $isofile
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile toram --
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
}
```

The `toram` item is critical.

Boot the computer selecting the above menuentry.

Unmount all partitions. To unmount the Live iso run:

`sudo umount -lrf /isodevice`

Confirm all partitions are unmounted. You should be running totally in RAM.

Run the Ubuntu installer. I generally use the **Something else** option.

You may want to run `sudo update-grub` on reboot.