# Install ISO from disk/partition - overcome usual hurdles

Tags: boot, grub2, iso

With help from my other Q&A [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1319271/grub-boot-an-iso-from-a-different-partition), I am able to get the ISO to boot, but not *install* it (yet :-/).

As per some Launchpad posts, the normal `initrd` present in the ISO will always look for
CD-ROM. So, I replaced it with the `initrd` designed for *hd-media* from here:

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-amd64/current/images/hd-media/initrd.gz
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-amd64/current/images/hd-media/vmlinuz

(although, I am not sure what is the exact difference)
With this, I could get past the CD-ROM mount, but installation gets into `mount` problem.
My ISO is on `/dev/sda5`, so when asked to `unmount` `/dev/sda`, I said "No", later it goes a
step further and errors out like "no root file system defined" etc.

Tried: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debian-installer/+bug/1347726
Didn't help.
Also tried using `toram` in the command line as per [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1155216) - didn't help.

I am using Ubuntu `18.04.4` *server* ISO here. However, just to try, I used Ubuntu `18.04.5` *Desktop* (live
CD boot) and that installed fine (even though it gave the error for mounted `/dev/sda`!)
What exactly is the delta that is missing in *Server* ISO that is present in *Desktop* /Live ISO
which makes this work!?

All I want is to install an ISO which is residing on one partition `/dev/sda5` to another -
`/dev/sda2` or `/dev/sda6`

Comment: **cdrom** is the root folder on a live USB unless live USB is boot from ISO file in which case the folder is named **isodevice**.

Comment: I am not using live USB, this is a plain old server ISO.

Comment: Yes, I see that. I do not have much experience with Server, but if you boot the ISO using GRUB2,  I think you will find the root folder is named **isodevice**. If you create a USB using Rufus, Etcher etc and boot that, I think your root folder will be named **cdrom**. You said something about cdrom missing. Also, you can not install to the drive you are booted from unless you boot `toram` and then unmount the partition containing isodevice. I wrote something about that once, I will have a look.

Comment: This should be similar to your needs: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1318013/how-to-install-ubuntu-from-iso-file/1318033#1318033

Comment: I did try with `toram` but still it tries to `unmount /dev/sda` and then goes to a bad state! There is some difference between the Desktop ISO (which has Live CD boot capability- and works well when booted this way from disk) vs the Server ISO! Have to check if I can get the best of both.

Comment: I have added a menuentry to boot ISO files on my HDD, to a Full install USB. (just sort of a proof of concept thing). Running an ISO booted from an external drive should not require Unmounting any partitions.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I could finally get this to work. The issue is, the installer _has_ to itself create some partition, if not it wont proceed. So, I deleted a partition and left some free space for it to grab, and used `d-i partman-auto/init_automatically_partition select biggest_free`